# Не заходит requests по ссылкам, выдает 404

Tags: python, requests, web-scraping

В общем я собрал ссылки в файл и хочу чтобы они перебирались в цикле,делаю все правильно, пример кода ниже:

```
def get_result_from_links(file_path):
    with open(f'{file_path}','r') as file:
        links = file.readlines()
    for i, link in enumerate(links):
        if not i%5==0:
            r = requests.get(url=link, headers=headers)
            r.encoding = 'cp1251'
            print(link)
            print(r.status_code)
            print(r.text)   
        else:
            print('Sleeping...')
            time.sleep(3)`
```

сделал чтобы читал линии, так как в файле ссылки записаны с новой строки, вот часть файла с ссылками:

```
https://stroit-kompanii.ru/list/exciton_elektromonta/
https://stroit-kompanii.ru/list/rittal_torgovaya_fir/
https://stroit-kompanii.ru/list/magazin_energosbereg/
https://stroit-kompanii.ru/list/servisnaya_kompaniya/
https://stroit-kompanii.ru/list/transstroisnab_torgo/
```

они идут каждая на новой строки, тут почему-то слитно.
И вот что я получаю на выводе:

```
Sleeping...
https://stroit-kompanii.ru/list/rittal_torgovaya_fir/

404


<h1>Страница не найдена</h1>

<p>страница к которой вы обратились не существует. <a href="/">вернуться на главную</a></p>
```

хотя, если открыть каждую ссылку отдельно в браузере то,все работает корректно, так же как и получить содержимое ссылки через другой файл, так же через requests, что делать?

И еще маленький вопрос на последок, я попытался сделать, чтобы скрипт "засыпал" на 3 сек после каждой 5-ой ссылки, но получается так, что первую ссылку он пропускает, как исправить?

Comment: "И вот что я получаю на выводе" вот почему у вас в выводе между url и 404 пустая строка? Как вы думаете?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_result_from_links(file_path):
    with open(f'{file_path}', 'r') as file:
        links = file.readlines()
    for i, link in enumerate(links, 1):
        if i % 5 == 0:
            print('Sleeping...')
            time.sleep(3)
            
        r = requests.get(link.strip())
        r.encoding = 'cp1251'
        print(link)
        print(r.status_code)
        print(r.text)
```